# Query Taking long time

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, rownum

I have the following query

```
 SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.a=B.b JOIN C ON A.a=C.c.
```

The above query return million rows and takes lot of time to return results. How can I see just first "N" records so that the query runs faster.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 100 * ...`

Comment: You can use SELECT Top n * from A....

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using Oracle

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you would just add `rownum` to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON A.a = B.b JOIN
     C
     ON A.a = C.c
WHERE rownum < 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hint [first_rows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#4942):

```
SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(100) */ * FROM A JOIN B ON A.a=B.b JOIN C ON A.a=C.c
```

Also check if you have indices on A.a, B.b and C.c.

As an addition you should understand that **any** sorting(`order by`), or analytic function, or `group by` operation, or `distinct` (maybe something else as well which requests the whole data set, e.g. `UNION` or `INTERSECT`) will destroy this hint and anyway will collect the whole dataset. They simply cannot work without it: e.g. how to order the data set if there is not the whole list presented?

Comment: The `FIRST_ROWS` *hint* doesn't limit the rows, although it may make returning the first rows faster.

Comment: yes, but I thought rownum is quite clear and the problem is to make it faster... Anyway, the biggest part of answer is about another thing

Comment: You're right, the OP's real problem is the performance of the query - but their most immediate question was how to limit the rows, and they don't appear to be familiar with the ROWNUM solution. But your answer is useful and I'm not downvoting it.

Answer (score -2):

You can get desired number of record with TOP Clause. Here is an example:-

```
SELECT TOP n *
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.a=B.b 
JOIN C ON A.a=C.C
```